# Oppening LMDB data FCN32 Semantic Segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, caffe, lmdb

I'm new with Caffe and all the ML stuff but I've been working with LeNet using LMDB files without any problem. Now, making a small test over my new Net (FCN32 semantic segmentation) it seems that always get stuck forever trying to open the file. I try with CPU and GPU. Any comment about it is welcome.

```
 I0614 12:34:29.158532 27812 net.cpp:100] Creating Layer mnist
 I0614 12:34:29.158545 27812 net.cpp:408] mnist -> data
 I0614 12:34:29.158573 27812 net.cpp:408] mnist -> label
 I0614 12:34:29.169967 27818 db_lmdb.cpp:35] Opened lmdb 
 /user/myname/LMDB_file
```

Comment: is it possible both train and test phase of your net are accessing the same lmdb? it seems like there's a lock on your dataset

Comment: Hi Shai!, thanks for your answer  but nope, I'm working with different lmdb for test and train and both aren't lock. I was thinking in something related to the kernel size (lack of memory?) or try it with a even smaller net (1 layer maybe?).

Comment: doesn't sound like memory issue. can you please post the prototxt part defining data layers?

Comment: please do not post such comments: it's unreadable. Edit your question instead

Comment: what about TEST phase input layer?

Comment: Thanks Shai!, my stuff is here: https://github.com/byaeggy/SSNet

Comment: your train and validation nets are the same. they both read from the SAME lmdb.

Comment: I'm giving different files, "pid_LMDB1X" for validation and "energy_LMDB1X" for train, do I need to have a different "net structure" for validation and train?.

Comment: Another thing, in my solver sometimes I set train and validation and sometimes I just turn off the validation, and in both cases I get the same issue.